# Talend - Read a SQL from .txt and pass variables to it

Tags: sql, talend

I need to read an Excel file and excecute a different SQL Query (Oracle) for each row of the Excel, depending on the value that a column ("tipo") of the table has. Also, I need to pass variables to the SQL query that comes from others columns of the same excel.

I have accomplished this with a tjava, creating a string that generates de query.. somthing like this (simplified):

```
String var1 = input_row.var1;
String var2 = input_row.var2;
String sql_query = ""

if (tipo.toString().equals(String.valueOf("Option1"))) {
query_ev = "select " + var1 + " as variable1, " + var2 + " as var 2 from dual";}

if (tipo.toString().equals(String.valueOf("Option2"))) {
query_ev = "select " + var1+ " from dual";}

context.sql = sql_query;
```

Nevertheless, my "problem" is that my queries are long, and this method only allows me to put them in the tjava whithout line breaks, so its very difficult to edit them since they remain a "one-row-query" in the tjava.

Is there a way to accomplish the same but having the queries formatted ?
for example, for Option1 having this

```
select " + var1 + " as variable1, " + var2 + " as var 2 
from dual
where 
 ...
```

I appreciate any clue.

Comment: are you printing it out on console to copy and run somewhere? If so you can add \n in places you want to move to next line and hence format better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query_ev = "select "
" + var1 + " as variable1, " + var2 + " as var 2 "+
from dual";
```

I am without Java right now to verify but I think this approach could help formatting. Just check that you have enough spaces - don't do this

`"as var 2"+"from dual"`

which would result in SQL like

`"as var 2from dual"`

Comment: Thanks, its a good approach. However, can you imagine any method to read the SQL from a .txt file ? That would be ideal, but the problem for me is the variables that I need to give the SQL in the tjava.

Comment: That is possible but depends on the format of the text file. You might want to open another question asking this especially.